# Solving this 1st Order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following 1st Order ODE:

$$(y^2 - xy) dx + (x^2 + xy) dy = 0$$

Here is my work so far:

$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{-y^2+xy}{x^2+xy}$$
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{-y^2+xy}{x^2+xy}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2}}=\frac{-\frac{y^2}{x^2}+\frac{y}{x}}{1+\frac{y}{x}}$$
$$y=vx\implies\frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-v^2+v}{1+v}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$$
$$x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{-v^2+v-v(1+v)}{1+v}=\frac{-2v^2}{1+v}$$
$$-\frac{1}{x}dx=\frac{1+v}{2v^2}dv$$
Integrating both sides, I get
$$-\ln\lvert x\rvert+C=\frac{-\frac{1}{v}+\ln\lvert v\rvert}{2}$$
$$-\ln\lvert x\rvert+C=\frac{-\frac{x}{y}+\ln\lvert\frac{y}{x}\rvert}{2}$$
After that line, I'm stuck. I do not know how to proceed. I know that the general solution must be an explicit $y$ in terms of $x$. I was absent when this was taught in class, and I'm really not sure about my solution in the first place.

What do I do here next?

Comment: General solution can also come in implicit form.

Comment: @Pacciu So, that last line is enough already I guess?

Comment: I didn’t check your computations, but I believe they’re correct. In such a case, your general solution cannot be solved for $y$ in terms of *elementary functions*, therefore an implicit general solution is the best you can get.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not always possible to find an explicit solution for $y$ as a function of $x$ or the other way around.

There is nothing wrong with the implicit solution either.

The problem with your equation is that you have implicit solution and it is fine.

Comment: Thank you kind sir :)